# Proper term for "hyperstable" algorithm>

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology

Say an iterative approximation algorithm is "hyperstable" if roundoff error  at one step simply doesn't matter, because it automatically gets corrected in succeeding steps.

For example, we approximate $\sqrt 2$ by saying $x_0=1$, $x_{n+1}=\frac12(x_n+2/x_n)$. Then $x_1=1.5$, but if we get  $x_1=1.49$ or $x_1=1.51$ because of roundoff error that doesn't matter, $x_n$ will still converge to $\sqrt 2$.

**Q:** What's the right word for "hyperstable"?

**My work so far:** Not much; I have a hard time figuring out an appropriate search term.

**Context:** Teaching Linear 101. A student asked if we were going to be doing Gauss-Seidel or Gauss-Jacobi. I had no idea - of course being a typical student in that class he was unable to clarify. I looked it up after class, and the answer is neither - we're talking about Gaussian elimination, which is simply not an iterative approximation algorithm.

So I'll be answering the question today, and it seems appropriate to talk a bit about stability.

**Q:** I have only a vague idea how G-S and G-J work. They are in fact hyperstable, yes?

**Note** The algorithm I think of as Gaussian elimination is definitely unstable. I gather there are tricks one can use to enhance the stability, but here I'm not talking about that - maybe my Gaussian elimination is "naive Gaussian elimination": Just do it assuming exact arithmetic, without worrying about numerical issues.

So Gaussian elimination is certainly unstable, meaning that tinny roundoff errors  can lead to huge errors in the answer. I realized the other day that it's actually "hyper-unstable", meaning that roundoff errors can take a system with a unique solution and convert it to a system with no solution at all!

**Q:** *Is* there a standard term for "hyper-unstable"?

**Example.** Say $\delta>0$ is so small that $1+\delta=1$ in floating-point. Consider the system $x+y+z=0$, $-x+\delta z=1$, $-x=2$. If we don't notice that it's silly because $x$ is given and we blindly apply $R_2=R_2+R_1$, $R_3=R_3+R_1$ we get $y+z=1,$ $y+z=2$.

Comment: We often distinguish "direct methods" from "iterative methods" in linear algebra.  Direct methods would give an exact answer in a finite number of steps if performed in exact arithmetic, and so may also be termed "exact methods".  Iterative methods, like Gauss-Seidel, aim to provide good approximate solutions after a moderate number of steps.  So there is a tradeoff contemplated between accuracy and effort.  These terms don't answer your stability question, but they might be helpful to frame Gaussian elimination as a direct method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen the term "self-correcting" used to describe what you call "hyper-stable". Invariably, the term is used in the context of fixed point iterations. 
The rounding errors are still relevant because they determine how accurately we can compute the limit, but they do not keep us from obtaining a good approximation.

As stated by @Lutz, the Gauss-Seidel and Jacobi iterations are examples of fixed point iterations and we could label them "self-correcting".

There are rather cases of algorithms where rounding errors bring actual benefits. The power method for computing a dominant eigenpair of a matrix is the only example that I can recall right now. In exact arithmetic you never converge if the initial guess is orthogonal to the dominant eigenspace. In floating point arithmetic, rounding errors will sooner rather than later give you component in the right direction and subsequent iterations will blow it up until it dominates.

I know of no term equivalent to "hyper-unstable" nor have I ever needed such a term. A problem is either solvable or insolvable. If it is solvable, then the distance to there nearest unsolveable problem is relevant. A solvable problem is either ill-conditioned or well-conditioned. If it is ill-conditioned, then I need to run the entire computation using, say, double precision, rather than single precision arithmetic. In any case, I will be using stable algorithms. If an algorithm is unstable for the given problem class, then it is useless for practical calculations. The degree of instability is irrelevant.

The label: "It works 99.9999% of the time" is a useless property for a piece of software whose errors can lead to loss of life, say, an auto-pilot, the controller of a close-in weapons system or the operating system for a power plant.

Comment: Thx. Regarding "The label: "It works 99.9999% of the time" is a useless property for a piece of software whose errors can lead to loss of life, say, an auto-pilot, the controller of a close-in weapons system or the operating system for a power plant.": Not quite life-or-death, but I had an ATM crash on me the other day.  The error message mentioned winatm.exe -  sounds like they're actually using MS Windows. Boggles the mind

Comment: (So I didn't get my money but didn't know whether my account had been debited. Went to the bank to  check - the guy said yes, some ATMs do use MS Windows -  he understood my bogglement at that. The installation should include a message "warning: not for use in situations requiring a reliable OS.")

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  The ATM example is good example which people can immediately relate to. I will add it to my collection. I believe that all programs should be proved correct, but this is a fanatical and unpopular position. I will settle for all programmers being trained to the point where they can prove their programs correct. Here "life-or-death" scenarios can help to shut down opposition to spending money towards that goal.

Answer (score 2):

Your examples for "hyper-stable" are all (converging) fixed-point iterations. If such a function is contracting, it converges by the Banach fixed-point theorem to the unique fixed point independent of the initial point in some neighborhood.

If you decompose $A=L+D+R$, into lower triangular, diagonal and upper triangular parts, then Gauß-Seidel is the iteration $$x_{n+1}=g(x_n)=(L+D)^{-1}(b-Rx_n)$$ and Jacobi is $$x_{n+1}=g(x_n)=D^{-1}(b-(L+R)x_n).$$

You can consider the Gauß elimination with rounding as an imperfect inverse and use it as a pre-conditioner for an iterative solver, if the result of the Gauß-elimination for $Ax=b$ is $x=Hb$, then you can iterate $$x_{n+1}=g(x_n)=x_n-H(Ax_n-b)$$ which is converging if $I-HA$ is small.

What you call "hyper-unstable" is more commonly called "ill-conditioned", small changes in the input cause large changes in the result, relative to the size of it.

Comment: Thanks. But (i) I know there's a more specific term  for "converges implies converges in a neighborhood", (ii) "small changes in the input cause large changes in the result" no, that's what I called "unstable". What I called "hyperunstable" is worse: Small changes in the input lead to no result at all (as in the example I gave).

Comment: It is still ill-conditioned, with condition number $O(δ^{-1})$. Ill-conditioned problem instances often or almost always are close to a singular problem instance, which your case $δ=0$ is. Singular obviously has "generally not solvable" as consequence.

Comment: I wasn't disputing that - yes, it's  clearly ill-conditioned, and yes, it's clear that an ill-conditioned problem will often be close to a singular problem. I was wondering if there's a specific term for an algorithm such that an ill-conditioned (but solvable with exact arithmetic) problem _can_ be unsolvable - saying this often or almost always happens doesn't tell me anything about the existence or non-existence of that term.